# How to center the navbar in bootsrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I'd like to know how I can center the navbar using columns in bootstrap. I'm a begginner using bootstrap. I need some advice. Thank you. You will find my code below. Let me know if its unclear.

here's my code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
 <span class="icon-bar"></span>
 <span class="icon-bar"></span>
 <span class="icon-bar"></span>

                </button> <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Example</a>

            </div>
            <!-- End navbar-header-->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="#">Example</a>

                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Example</a>

                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Example</a>

                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Example</a>

                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!--end row-->
    </div>
    <!--End container fluid-->
</nav>
<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
<script src="Bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you want to do this with columns?

Answer (score 0):

You can center entire navbar by useing `<div class="container">` instead of `<div class="container-fluid">`.
I hope it will help.